# Regex in GoogleDocs search-and-replace

Tags: regex, replace, google-docs

I want to replace all first "/" with "[" but all second "/" with "]". GoogleDocs offers a regular expression search-and-replace, but I have no clue how to use that for this "first and second" issue. Example of source and target below.

What do I have to enter in the Search and Replace fields of GoogleDocs dialogue?

current state

```
p pen /pen/
b bad /bæd/
t tea /tiː/
```

intended solution

```
p pen [pen]
b bad [bæd]
t tea [tiː]
```

Comment: take advantage of the space before the first slash. replace `<space>/` with `[` and then `/` with `]`. You shouldn't need regex here.

Comment: Google Docs Find and Replace does not support replacement backreferences, it is not clear how to do that without them. Try `/\b` to replace the first and `\b/` to replace the second slash.

Comment: It's a very long table. Unfortunenately, in many cases there is a tab #9 and not a #32 in front of the slash. But yes, a nice idea as work-around. However, I hoped to learn to to use regular expressions with "first" and "second" occurences here and how to keep whatever is in-between.

Comment: With normal regex, it is [trivial](https://regex101.com/r/IrgXAX/1), not Google Docs.

Comment: Thanks for the "trivial" solution. So GoogleDocs cannot do this? How do they intend this feature to be used?

Comment: @HJay you could still use the same work around. Just replace <space> with whatever is behind the first slash. In Regex, `\t` is a tab character. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Sheets you can use capture groups so you could do something like 
Find: /(.*)/
Replace with: [$1]

[Docs does not support this functionality](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expressions) so you may have to move your stuff around a little.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it works in Google Sheets. The answer of Wiktor solved the replacement issue.